# How do I query SQlite using python and then compare the query result?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-3.4

The aim of this code is to validate a password that is entered using the passwords and usernames stored in a database. The table contains username (`nick`) and password, passwords are encrypted using `db.crypt`.

My code at the moment consists of:

```
def check_login(db, username, password):
    """returns True if password matches stored"""
    cursor = db.cursor()
    pass1 = db.crypt(password)
    cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE nick=?", (username,))
    passcheck = cursor.fetchone()
    if passcheck == pass1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But i keep getting an assertion error when running a unit test:

```
   line 29, in test_check_login
        self.assertTrue(users.check_login(self.db, username, password), "Password check failed for username%s" % username)
    AssertionError: False is not true : Password check failed for nick jake
```

When I use print to show what `passcheck` is retrieving it prints the correct encrypted pass word but inside of `('')` tags (as a tuple, I believe). But when I print `cursor.fetchone()` it says `None`. I'm unsure what is going wrong here, I encrypted the password being sent into the function so it can be correctly matched to that of the password stored in the DB. I assume `passcheck` would retrieve the password that corresponds to the user `nick`, that is passed through the function.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cursor.fetchone()
```

fetches *a row as a tuple*:

```
passcheck == ("hashed password", )
```

You must compare agains `passcheck[0]` or unpack the tuple:

```
passcheck, = cursor.fetchone()
```

**Edit:** Let the database do the comparing:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= ? and password= ?",
    (username, pass1))
found = cursor.fetchone()
if found:
    # user exists and password matches
else:
    # user does not exist or password does not match
```

Comment: Not a list, a tuple. But yes. `passcheck, = cursor.fetchone()` is a handy shortcut to get the first column assigned to a variable.

Comment: When i try passcheck, = cursor.fetchone() it says Nonetype object is not iterable.

Comment: Then you have no match. Use `passcheck = cursor.fetchone()` and check that `passcheck != None` before accessing `[0]`.

Comment: Thats the thing though when i use passcheck = cursor.fetchone()[0] AND i dont use the line "if passcheck1 == pass1:" the print value for passcheck matches pass1. But when i try to compare passcheck1 == pass1 i get the error nonetype object is not subscriptable and also for some reason all my print statements seem to occur multiple times but with different results.